# How can I use MVC partial views and layouts in Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Is this possible to do? I have the majority of my web app in MVC.

But I am going to set up a tech corner where I just want to go to simple Razor pages instead of setting up complicated endpoints to get there in StartUp.

Seems like pages would be better to organize simple pages like:

articles/AspNetCore3  -- list out related articles

articles/AspNetCore3/WhatsNew -- set up article here

articles/AspNetCore3/Blazor -- talk about this new technology here

articles/Azure/Overview -- these kinds of URLs with simple
content but Razor Page ready to add functionality if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@RenderPage("_MenubarPage.cshtml");`.

You can also use `@RenderPage("_MenuPage.cshtml", MyModel)` which allows you to supply any model you like to the view by including it as a second parameter.

You can also use `@{Html.RenderPartial("_articles/AspNetCore3/WhatsNew");}` if you are using a partial. But don't forget that you need to wrap it with the razor code block `@{}`

The file path may be different depending on where you are rendering the Partial from.

In regards to using a Layout page, you simply just state what Layout you would like at the top of the cshtml page. Example below:

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.ProjectModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test Page";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

You can also use the `<partial>` tag to render a partial in .NETCore 3.1. Example below:

```
<partial name="Shared/_ProductPartial.cshtml" for="Product">
```

Tag helpers are the *new* *thing* in .NET Core. The HTML Tag helpers still exist for backwards compatability.

Microsoft Docs on Partial tags are located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Can I use the <partial> tag helper?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can. <partial name="Shared/_ProductPartial.cshtml">. Here is a good link on Partial Tags. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Updated my answer to include the partial tag.